# net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED axios

Tags: javascript

Hey Everyone I keep getting this error when trying to retrieve data from the server side using Axios. I have flushed my dns etc... cleared browser data but nothings working any idea? thank you

`````
GET http://locahost:5000/api/activities net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

dispatchXhrRequest  @   xhr.js:184
xhrAdapter  @   xhr.js:13
dispatchRequest @   dispatchRequest.js:52
Promise.then (async)        
request @   Axios.js:61
Axios.<computed>    @   Axios.js:76
wrap    @   bind.js:9
getAllActivities    @   agent.js:19
(anonymous) @   App.js:22
commitHookEffectListMount   @   react-dom.development.js:19731
commitPassiveHookEffects    @   react-dom.development.js:19769
callCallback    @   react-dom.development.js:188
invokeGuardedCallbackDev    @   react-dom.development.js:237
invokeGuardedCallback   @   react-dom.development.js:292
flushPassiveEffectsImpl @   react-dom.development.js:22853
unstable_runWithPriority    @   scheduler.development.js:653
runWithPriority$1   @   react-dom.development.js:11039
flushPassiveEffects @   react-dom.development.js:22820
(anonymous) @   react-dom.development.js:22699
workLoop    @   scheduler.development.js:597
flushWork   @   scheduler.development.js:552
performWorkUntilDeadline    @   scheduler.development.js:164````
`````

Comment: Have you validated that https://locahost:5000/api/activities opens via the browser directly or postman and you do no receive any invalid certificates or other interrupts.

Comment: Do you have `https` set up in localhost? Does someone is listening for `5000` port on your server? If that is remote server, then he can not access your localhost

Comment: Thanks for replies guys, locahost:5000..... opens via the browser directly without issue

Comment: I have solved it...... a stupid typo haha my bad thanks guys anyway

Comment: @Justina Could we close this question?

Answer (score 4):

For those who missed - there's typo in *locahost*. Should be *localhost*, or *locahost* should be configured to resolve locally to *127.0.0.1* (or whatever target IP is, depends on OS used)

Comment: I also faced this issue due to typo mistake on api endpoint